# use sqlserver for local based app

Tags: sql-server, wpf, database, winforms, sql-server-express

I'm working currently on a windows form application which uses a Database, and i want to use MS SqlServer, now i need to know how to make it local based..
In other words : after publishing the app and install it on another device, it'll crash because of the database not found and the connection string also not right.
I've find on many threads a way to copy the md5 file from SqlServer directory to the project files and change the connection string to local, but it didn't work properly as it is still crashing on other devices, so what should i do in this case ?
Also is there any software i should install it on other devices in order to use sqlServer commands (like .Net Framework..etc), and also what is SqlServer Express ?, is it the thing i'm looking for ?
Please explain in details, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check out LocalDb https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using SQL Server Compact 4.0, so far so good

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact 
Basically you need to create DB file and carry it over to destination machine with some additional assemblies.

You can download it from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876

There is also extension for Visual studio that allows you to work with it using designers. With it you can use Entity Framework which.

http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/